# thread_specific_ptr thread safe access

Tags: boost, boost-thread, thread-local, thread-local-storage

I have the following code snippet

```
class MCSLock
{
  static boost::thread_specific_ptr< mcs_lock > tls_node;

  public:
  MCSLock()
  {
   if( tls_node.get() == 0 )
     tls_node.reset( new mcs_lock() );
  }
};
```

My understand is that each thread has it's own space allowed for tls_node. This means
the constructor in which we call get() and reset() are thread safe.

Is my understanding correct ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each call will be received by different (thread local) objects.